# How to implement a rotation scheme with rsync

Tags: rsync

I have an ever growing remote directory of files that I'd like to sort and filter before I `rsync` them, with the goal of always keeping only the latest N files in my destination directory (i.e. a rotation scheme, more or less). Since `rsync` doesn't seem to have options for this, I've been using the technique of "inserting an arbitrary remote command", described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/950062/787842

with which I came up with this command, that I execute as a cron on the destination host:

```sh
rsync -vrzO --delete \
    -e ssh <remote_host>:'$(cd <remote_dir> && ls -t $PWD/* | head -n 25)' \
    <destination_dir>
```

This works well the first time (i.e. when the dest dir is empty): only the 25 freshest files get copied. But then when the window "slides forward" (i.e. when the arrival of a newer file should push an older one out, locally), the problem is that the `--delete` option doesn't work as I'd expect. My guess is that since the filtered out remote files still exist (i.e. they're just being temporarily hidden by the inserted `'$(..)'` command), then `rsync` simply cannot filter them out locally. Is my understanding correct, and is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate your command as,

`rsync -vrzO --delete -e ssh <remote_host>:'<remote_dir>/file1 <remote_dir>/file2' <destination_dir>/`  i.e. substituting output of `cd <remote_dir> && ls -t $PWD/* | head -n 2`.

rsync's `--delete` works on directories and your **command substitution** is providing list of files. So `--delete` is not working.

Excerpt from `man rsync`:

> --delete
>
> This tells rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving side
>   (ones that aren’t on the sending side), **but only  for the 
>   directories**  that  are being  synchronized.   You  **must have asked
>   rsync to send the whole directory** (e.g. "dir" or "dir/") without using
>   a wildcard for the directory’s contents (e.g. "dir/*") since the
>   wildcard is expanded by the shell and rsync thus gets a request to
>   transfer individual files,  not  the  files’  parent directory.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first part of our answer: what do you mean by "simulating my command"? So the conclusion is that what I want to do (with a single rsync call) is simply impossible, is that it?

Comment: That means you can try your command by explicitly putting few file names in place of the command to be substituted which is giving you the list of latest files.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the remote directory over [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). Then you can treat it as a local directory.

Now, to sort files by modification time, the easiest way is [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/)'s [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). The 25 most recent files in a directory are

```
*(NDom[1,25])
```

So, if you want to copy first, then delete the extraneous files at the destination:

```
for x in source/*(NDom[1,25]); do
  y=destination/${x:t}
  if [[ ! -e $y || $x -nt $y ]]; then cp -p $x $y; fi
done
destination_files=(destination/*(NDom[1,25]))
if [[ ${#destination_files} -gt 25 ]]; then
  shift $((${#destination_files} - 25)) destination_files
  rm $destination_files
fi
```

Here's another method that deletes files before copying. This one deletes the oldest file when it's about to copy a new file and there is already a full complement at the destination.

```
destination_files=(destination/*(ND)); destination_count=$#destination_files
for x in source/*(NDom[1,25]); do
  y=destination/${x:t}
  if [[ $destination_count -gt 25 && ! -e $y ]]; then rm destination/*(NDom[-1]); fi
  if [[ ! -e $y || $x -nt $y ]]; then cp -p $x $y; fi
done
```

(Warning: the code above was typed directly into the browser, I did not test it.)